# Changing theme mode in Material UI react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, themes, react-context

I am trying to implement a theme toggle functionality in my react app, that toggles from light to dark theme. I can successfully toggle theme mode but it doesn't persist over page changes. I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and can't seem to make any progress.

this is my code:

App.jsx:

```
//imports

// Define light theme
const lightTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'light',
  },
});

// Define dark theme
const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
    // Add other dark theme properties as needed
    primary: {
      main: '#9985ff', //'#85beff' Customize the primary color
    },
  },
});

function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('light');

  const toggleThemeMode = () => {
    setMode((prevMode) => (prevMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'));
  }

  const theme = React.useMemo(
    () => (mode === 'light' ? lightTheme : darkTheme),
    [mode]
  );

  return (
    <ThemeModeContext.Provider value={toggleThemeMode}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/event/:eventid' element={<Event />} />
            {/*other routes*/}
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ThemeModeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

theme-context.jsx:

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

const ThemeModeContext = createContext({
  toggleThemeMode: () => {},
});

export { ThemeModeContext };
```

and i have an DrawerNavbar component that is a part of every page component and it's where i have the button that has the functionality of changing the theme:

```
{/*i just copied the main parts*/}
const theme = useTheme();
const toggleThemeMode = useContext(ThemeModeContext);

<IconButton color='inherit' onClick={toggleThemeMode}>
  {theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? (
    <Brightness7Icon />
  ) : (
    <Brightness4Icon />
  )}
</IconButton>
```

I tryed a lot of things ... none were a solution, i made a custom useThemeHook it only worked while i had the DrawerNavbar component inside the App component but that is not an option. The only other thing i have thought of is prop drilling and passing in the toggleThemeMode down to the DrawerNavbar inside props, but there has to be a way to do it using Context